# Merge a list of dataframes keeping unique names (avoid duplicating names and NAs)

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to merge a list of dataframes keeping unique names (avoid duplicating the names that are repeated across all dataframes). I have 4 dataframes with different number of rows each and I need to combine them all so that I only get the participants who took **all** tests

I get this, with Nas:

[image]

Variables:

```
class1Time1 : took VarA and VarB tests in 2021
class2Time1 : took VarA and VarB tests in 2021

class1Time1 : took VarA and VarB tests in 2022
class2Time1 : took VarA and VarB tests in 2022

so, "Var_Year" stands for the grades of each subject in the target year, but note that
not every subject took all tests
```

This is a simplified made-up version of my data

```
### create a similar data frame:

names1 <- c("Mary","John","Kate", "Bea", "Harry", "Hermione", "Rony", "Dobby")
names2 <- c("Harry", "Hermione", "Rony", "Dobby", "Dumbledore", "Snape", "Sirius")

class1Time1 <- data.frame(ID = names1[3:8], VarA_21 = sample(1:20, 6), VarB_21 = sample(1:20, 6))
class2Time1 <- data.frame(ID = names2[1:7], VarA_21 = sample(1:20, 7), VarB_21 = sample(1:20, 7))
class1Time2 <- data.frame(ID = names1[2:8], VarA_22 = sample(1:20, 7), VarB_22 = sample(1:20, 7))
class2Time2 <- data.frame(ID = names2[1:4], VarA_22 = sample(1:20, 4), VarB_22 = sample(1:20, 4))

### So, the only students that took all tests were "Harry" "Hermione" "Rony" "Dobby"  

### Ok, now I'm taking all dataframes from the environment and putting them into a list:

together <- grep("class",names(.GlobalEnv), value=TRUE)

##### put into a list 

my_list <- do.call("list", mget(together))

### Now I need ONLY the same names from all dataframes

test <- Reduce(function(...) full_join(...), my_list) ### doens't work

### I've tried merge(), rbind(), etc...
```

**Note**: I've tried to reproduce my actual data, but I couldn't do that without changing my participant's real names, that's why I've made the made-up version, but my actual data looks like this:

[image: actual]

**Question 1**: how can I join all dataframes so that I have only one row per participants who took all tests ?

**Question 2**: If I can get Q1, then I believe that a simple `filter` would work afterwards to keep only complete.cases I suppose, right?

I've seen many solutions here including `merge()`, `reduce`, `rbind`, `join (by = "ID)`, but none seemed to help me (I've tried them all). Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I guess that I got closer with `test <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by="ID"), my_list)`, but it doesn't keep the columns original names, it duplicates the columns now

Comment: `Reduce(left_join, my_list)` ? If not, it might help to show a literal frame of your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in discussion above it's hard to know what might be going on with your data to drop all rows. However there's perhaps a few things you can do to help pinpoint/fix problems:

- at the moment, your four dataframes have duplicated column names, and within each dataframe it doesn't "know" what class it belongs to. That's why columns are being duplicated in the above example. Tidying data would help here by inserting 'class' name to dataframes before merging.
- pivoting to change the shape of the data would make `bind_rows` a simple way to combine all the comparable values across times/tests.
- joining all at first would let you visually check that parts are there for expected people, then you can filter across all columns.

Here's a working of the above data using `purrr` and `dplyr` to manipulate lists and data frames:

```r
library(tidyverse)

names1 <- c("Mary","John","Kate", "Bea", "Harry", "Hermione", "Rony", "Dobby")
names2 <- c("Harry", "Hermione", "Rony", "Dobby", "Dumbledore", "Snape", "Sirius")

class1Time1 <- data.frame(ID = names1[3:8], VarA_21 = sample(1:20, 6), VarB_21 = sample(1:20, 6))
class2Time1 <- data.frame(ID = names2[1:7], VarA_21 = sample(1:20, 7), VarB_21 = sample(1:20, 7))
class1Time2 <- data.frame(ID = names1[2:8], VarA_22 = sample(1:20, 7), VarB_22 = sample(1:20, 7))
class2Time2 <- data.frame(ID = names2[1:4], VarA_22 = sample(1:20, 4), VarB_22 = sample(1:20, 4))

together <- grep("class",names(.GlobalEnv), value=TRUE)
my_list <- do.call("list", mget(together))

my_list |>
  imap( ~ mutate(.x, class = str_extract(.y, "class\\d"))) |>
  map(
    pivot_longer,
    starts_with("Var"),
    names_to = "test_time",
    values_to = "score"
  ) |>
  reduce(bind_rows) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(class, test_time),
              values_from = score) |>
  # This final line reduces down to only full rows. Can be cut out for checking.
  filter(if_all(.fns = ~!is.na(.x)))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 9
#>   ID       class2_VarA_21 class2_VarB_21 class2_VarA_22 class2_VarB_22
#>   <chr>             <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>
#> 1 Harry                13             13              8              4
#> 2 Hermione              4              6              9              2
#> 3 Rony                 15             15             16              8
#> 4 Dobby                17             19             13             18
#> # … with 4 more variables: class1_VarA_21 <int>, class1_VarB_21 <int>,
#> #   class1_VarA_22 <int>, class1_VarB_22 <int>
```

Comment: thank you! I guess that It worked now! I have a few questions, if you don't mind: what is this part here ```imap( ~ mutate(.x,```  before str_ doing? and in the ```filter()``` , what ```.fns = ``` stands for?

Comment: good questions! `imap(...)` is saying "for each element in this list (`.x` represents each dataframe), do the function `mutate` to create a new column called `class` with the first part of the element's name (extracted from `.y` - which are the names of the dataframes you put in the list)". in the `filter` part, the `if_all` says "only keep row if all columns pass the function defined in `.fns`" and the function there is to check that each column (`.x` again) is *not* NA.

Comment: The first two parts before joining could be made much simpler by having each dataframe contain a "class" column and a "time" column before columns for each test score with matching names across all class/time combinations. That's what those `imap` and `map` commands are producing, but there may be simpler data-entry approaches to make your data suit your purposes. Hope this helps!

Comment: woww, yes! it helped a lot :) I got the points, thank you. there's just one thing that I didn't understand in total, tho, the ```.fns``` part ? what ```.fns``` stands for?

Comment: from `?across` - `.fns - Functions to apply to each of the selected columns`, i.e. you name/define a function to test each column for `TRUE`/`FALSE` values.

Comment: ohhhhh, now I got it! thank you once more :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use inner joins here, as long as you specify in `merge()` that you are joining only on `ID`

```
Reduce(\(a,b) merge(a,b, by="ID"),my_list)
```

Output

```
        ID VarA_21.x VarB_21.x VarA_22.x VarB_22.x VarA_21.y VarB_21.y VarA_22.y VarB_22.y
1    Dobby         8         5        19         9         7        13         3         3
2    Harry        14         1         4        16        12         4        20         9
3 Hermione         4         4        14         4         1        17        14         6
4     Rony        18        18         7        18         2         9         7         2
```

Note: `Reduce(merge, my_list)` will by default inner join each of these in turn, but there are no matching results in the end because you have common column names beyond just `ID` (but different "scores in those columns)

Comment: hi, thank you, what does the part ```Reduce(\(a,b)``` stand for? (I'm getting a a dataframe with 0 rows)

Comment: `Reduce(\(a,b)...)` is the same as `Reduce(function(a,b)...)`

Comment: oh, got, it, It didn't work :( I'll try to make an edit with my real dataset again

Comment: What doesn't work? If you run my solution on your provided code, it returns the 4 rows shown in `Output` above.

Comment: hi, I don't know...I'm trying to post my actual data, but I can't get rid of the participant's actual names without messing them up (since each data contains different names). I have 8 dfs, 2 per class, each class made 2 tests A/B in conditions 1/2 each year. Class1Cond1Year20 has 13obs,  Class1Cond2Year20 too;  Class1Cond1Year21 has 16 obs, Class1Cond2Year21 has 15 obs;   Class2Cond1Year20 has 8obs,  Class2Cond2Year20 too;  Class2Cond1Year21 has 12 obs, Class2Cond2Year21 has 11 obs; totaling 8 dfs in my list

Comment: I know that only 21 participants took all tests, but I didn't want to filter them in each dataframe separatedly

Comment: that could feasibly happen if there were no `ID`s shared across all dataframes, caused potentially by different ways of recording names/initials in each place perhaps? You could try running `Reduce(\(a,b) {df <- merge(a,b, by="ID"); print(df); df}, x = my_list)` which would print each step of merging the next dataframe and you could pinpoint where it drops all rows.

Comment: @AndyBaxter hi, so, I do have shared IDs (I know that, in total, I have 21 ID who appear as complete cases for all 8 dataframes)...ps: why can't I keep the common column names? it always creates new collumns